# no "" in java.library.path even when exists

Tags: java-native-interface, java.library.path

I have a java project in eclipse. I have placed the .so file under the libs\armeabi. Then I have entered the native library location from the workspace in JRE buildin path. When I execute my code it gives the error no "PC700" in java.library.path.

I have a file Test.java

```
public class Test {

{
    try{
        System.loadLibrary("PC700");
    } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] argv)
{
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    Test o = new Test();
    System.out.println("Helloooo");
}
```

}

The answer from the above code is

```
C:\XXXXX\XXX\XXXX\libs\armeabi

no PC700 in java.library.path

Helloooo
```

And when I search in the directory specified above I can find the library libPC700.so.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

From your library path it seems like you're running on a windows system. The file libPC700.so looks like a file created for a linux OS. On windows loadLibrary would expect a file named PC700.dll.